# Resize UITextField on Edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in my view which has size constraints to lay out it's position. What I want to happen is for the UITextField to change in width when a user begins to edit the field.

I have the view controller set as a delegate for the field and I have the delegate method working here

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"Search Field is being edited");

}
```

What I need to know is what do I need to do to `textField` to make it's width change as everything I've tried doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: If I do `textField.text = @"Yes!"` the field does change to Yes! so I know I have the correct setup. I just need to know how to change the width.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Objective-C so it's all learning for me. I've tried `[textField setFrame:<#(CGRect)#>]` but this didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set an outlet for the width constraint of your textfield.
In the following example i am gonna suppose its name is textFieldWidthConstraint

in your `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method add this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // no animation
    self.textFieldWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth;

    // animation
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
    {
        self.textFieldWidthConstraint.constant = newWidth;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

you could do the same thing for the height.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: +1. Since Glenn uses Autolayout and constraints, I would also go that way. This solution also allows animations in a very simple and clean way, as explained by Jad.

Answer (score 1):

have u tried using addTarget:action:forControlEvents?
(below i use Masonry to setup constraints in code)

somewhere:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
[textField setBackgroundColor:kBlackColor];
[textField setTextColor:kWhiteColor];
[textField setText:@"TEXT"];
[self.view addSubview:textField];
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) UIControlEventEditingChanged];
[textField mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerX);
    make.centerY.equalTo(self.view.mas_centerY);
    make.width.equalTo(@100);
    make.height.equalTo(@20);
}];
```

and

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGSize size = [textField sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, textField.frame.size.height)];
    CGFloat minimumWidth = MAX(100, size.width);

    [textField mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.equalTo(@(minimumWidth));
    }];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: I don't particularly want to use a Framework. There must be a way of doing it out of the box

Comment: masonry is a (very) powerful pod for doing constraints in code. you could also IBOutlet your NSLayoutConstraint and set the constant's value

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `.size` for it and setting it to a `CGSize` of whatever you want.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGSize

Comment: Property 'size' not found on object of type 'UITextField *' - I don't think I can use .size

Comment: i think he means 'textField.frame.size' although this won't hold when using AutoLayout